# Error converting data type varchar to float in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve for this error message "Error converting data type varchar to float" in the code below. I have tried many ways and this first line has worked. I think the problem is that there is a NULL in the table. Also the data type is `float` this time around.

```
SELECT
   'May' as Month_Name -- have this for all table months that I pull data from.
   , SUM(
      CASE
      WHEN [All Gaps Mar] = '-' THEN 0
      ELSE [All Gaps Mar]
      END
   ) AS AllGapsFeb -- works  with Integer on column in other tables
  , SUM(
      CASE
      WHEN coalesce([All Gaps Mar], 0) = '-' THEN 0
      ELSE [All Gaps Mar]
      END
   ) AS AllGapsMarch
```

Here are other attempts at getting it to work from what I found on SO and the internet, but I get the same error:

```
   , SUM(
      CASE
      WHEN [All Gaps Mar] = '-' THEN convert(integer, [All Gaps Mar])
      ELSE ([All Gaps Mar])
      END
   ) AS AllGapsMarch
   , SUM(
      CASE
      WHEN [All Gaps Mar] = '-' THEN 0
      ELSE convert(integer, [All Gaps Mar])
      END
   ) AS AllGapsMarch
   , CASE
      WHEN [All Gaps Mar] = '-'
         THEN ISNUMERIC(convert(integer, Sum([All Gaps Mar])))
      ELSE 0
      END AS numeric_count
```

Comment: Why are you doing coalese with 0 and comparing result with a string?

Comment: Can you check your column for any non numeric values other than -?    It is likely throwing an error whenever the column has an alphabetical character that can't be turned into a number.

Comment: What do you mean by this:  " --<works  with Integer on column in other tables"?   Try removing the SUM() and look at the data you are trying to SUM.   Are there any rows that aren't either numbers or NULLs?

Comment: @Yuriy - i was just trying to try something else. thats why i tried coalesce. i put that there so people could see that that would not work either.

Comment: @Tab Alleman by --<--<works with Integer on column in other tables. is that that case statement works in another script i have for a similar report i run. They have it as an Integer instead of Float type. Sorry if i didnt make that clearer.

Comment: What is an integer instead of a float type?   because if your [All Gaps Mar] column allows the '-' character, it can't be a float datatype.

Comment: @TabAlleman- it is a Float type with a dash"-" and a Null for data in that column. Sorry i did not create table. Dont know why they chose Float. I just have to figure out how to sum up the data in there for several months.

Comment: P.S. What version of SQL Server? I'd like to know which of my solutions helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 and up:

```
SELECT
   AllGapsMarch = Sum(Coalesce(Try_Convert(float, [All Gaps Mar])), 0)
```

In SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT
   AllGapsMarch = Sum(Convert(float, Coalesce(N.[All Gaps Mar]), 0))
FROM
   #adhoc A
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT [All Gaps Mar] WHERE IsNumeric(A.[All Gaps Mar] + 'E0') = 1
   ) N
```

In SQL Server 2000 and earlier:

```
SELECT
   AllGapsMarch = Sum(Convert(float, (
      CASE
      WHEN IsNumeric([All Gaps Mar] + 'E0') = 1 THEN [All Gaps Mar]
      ELSE 0
      END
   ))
```

I do have to say that storing month names in columns is NOT best practice. The month should be a value in a column instead of having one column for each month, and then only at the very last minute the presentation layer can pivot the result to provide each month's values in columns.

Here's a query to provoke some thought about unpivoting the awful months-as-separate-columns paradigm:

```
SELECT
   G.MonthNumber,
   [All Gaps] = Coalesce(Sum(N.ConvertableValue), 0)
FROM
   #adhoc A
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      ('1', [All Gaps Jan]),
      ('2', [All Gaps Feb]),
      ('3', [All Gaps Mar]),
      ('4', [All Gaps Apr]),
      ... and so on
   ) G (MonthNumber, StringValue)
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT G.Value
      WHERE IsNumeric(G.Value + 'E0') = 1
   ) N (ConvertableValue)
;
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Your last comment about awful months thing was funny. :). It gets worse though. I use that since i have to use tables for each month that this enormous report is run and then sum up all the details for each month and compare month to month for 170+ column excel report. That is why i use the Month_Name to i can then take the sum of each report month table. Why they stored this as float, i dont know. its a pain though.

Comment: Did I answer your question? About months--I stand by my comment. Summing up months when unpivoted is as easy as group by, comparing months is as easy as subtracting the right amount or `DateAdd(month, -1, MonthDate)`.

Comment: Yes you did. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error when trying to reproduce this but realised that my problem was caused by trying to populate my dummy data- the original version of the SELECT...UNION had all of the float values as numbers so I was doing SELECT 101, SELECT 16.6, and so on.  Trying to UNION float and varchar data without either using a CAST to ensure that they were all the same type or enclosing the numbers in quotes gave me the same message you were seeing...does using something like the query below get you what you need?

```
CREATE TABLE #adhoc ([All Gaps Mar] varchar(20),OtherField varchar(20))

INSERT INTO #adhoc
SELECT '101','ABC'
UNION
SELECT '16.6','123'
UNION
SELECT '3.14','May'
UNION
SELECT 'Not Numeric','March'
UNION
SELECT '42.0','Feb'
UNION
SELECT 'abc','Test'

SELECT 'May' as Month_Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([All Gaps Mar])=1 THEN CAST([All Gaps Mar] AS float) ELSE 0  END) Total 
FROM #adhoc 

/* alternate approach */
SELECT 'May' Month_Name, SUM(CAST([All Gaps Mar] as float)) 
FROM
(
SELECT [All Gaps Mar] FROM #adhoc WHERE ISNUMERIC([All Gaps Mar])=1
) tmp

DROP TABLE #adhoc
```